# Correlate php temporary file to apache web request

Tags: php, linux, apache

On a linux box running Apache for a public site, temporary files are being created in /tmp presumably by PHP as they have a “php” prefix.  How can I correlate this to the specific web request that caused php to write this file? I believe this is from file data being posted to non-existant URLs that is being temporary saved to the file system while the various PHP code decides if the file exists.

I’ve turned on auditd watching of /tmp and can generally match the timestamp to Apache logs, buy ideally I’d like to be able to point to a log showing the request and/or php file that caused php to write the file.

I’ve turned on trace logging of apache and php logging, but not seeing any way to capture that temporary file name.  Is this possible?

Comment: Tough one, I would also like to hear the answer if anyone has it. FYI any programming language that exists (pretty much) can create .php files so keep that in mind.

Comment: If you have a php file that is included on all your other files (or the index.php of a framework if you're using one), you can check there if there are files coming from the request, get the current path (it will be the path to the file on /tmp) and write that information (file path, current script, user ip address, etc) to a log file.